# ios drawViewHierarchyInRect crash EXC_BREAKPOINT UNKNOWN

Tags: ios, ios7

I have this random crash in my IOS app that is happening every now and then. 
Not able to replicate it at all but I have thousands of crash reports from users.

It is crashing with "EXC_BREAKPOINT UNKNOWN" during a call to [UIView drawViewHierarchyInRect:].

It only happens on IOS7 devices since the method is not available(and thus not called) before IOS7.

Does anybody have any idea at all on how to approach this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
- (UIImage *)imageRepresentation
{
    if (![self respondsToSelector:@selector(drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:)]) {
        // Disable imageRepresentation on < iOS 7
        return nil;
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, YES, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BREAKPOINT UNKNOWN at 0x0000defe
 raw
0
CoreFoundation  
CFRelease + 1131
1
UIKit   
-[UIView(Rendering) _imageFromRect:] + 136
2
UIKit   
-[UIView(Rendering) _imageFromRect:] + 136
3
UIKit   
-[UIView _drawViewHierarchyInRect:] + 174
4
UIKit   
-[UIView drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:] + 378
5
MyApp   
UIView+SSToolkitAdditions.m line 23
-[UIView(SSToolkitAdditions) imageRepresentation]
```

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint. Show us the code that is causing the crash.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I had a crash using the same API when the target view was not visible yet (had not a valid superview and window).

I've worked it around by not calling drawViewHierarchyInRect if self.superview or self.window were nil.

Answer (score 0):

If your UIView's height is nearly zero(such as 0.1), `drawViewHierarchyInRect: afterScreenUpdates:` will crash. So check the size before you call it.